# RedirectToAction doesn't happen when I start with an AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

`RedirectToAction` "doesn't work" when is use an ajax call, why is that?

The Login action sends me to the action Index with RedirectToAction, so I can see that view is returned. And the AJAX call end up in `done`.
Why doesn't the URL change to ../home/index as I would expect?

If I in `done` manually call `window.location.href = "/WebConsole53";` I will get the redirect I want, but I would rather use the redirect on the server. Can someone figure out what is the problem? Thanks.

Ajax call:

```
$('#btnLogin').on('click', function() {
    var url = urlHelper.getUrl('Account/login');
    var data = {
        username: $('#inputLoginUsername').val(),
        password: $('#inputLoginPassword').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    })
    .done(function (html) {
        console.log('done login');
        //window.location.href = "/mySite"; // this works
    })
    .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('failed');
    });
});
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password/*, LoginViewModel model*/, string returnUrl)
{
    //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
    //    return View(model);
    //}

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    //switch (result)
    //{
    //    case SignInStatus.Success:
    //        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    //    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
    //        return View("Lockout");
    //    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
    //        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    //    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    //    default:
    //        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    //        return View(model);
    //}

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    //return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home");
    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    //return RedirectToAction("ShowDashboard", "Dashboard");
}
```

Home Index:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
//            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
//            return RedirectToAction("ShowDashboard", "Dashboard");
}
```

**Solution - full credit goes to @Stephen Muecke**

Use of form submit from html.helper see doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("login", "Account"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
```

Comment: Because the whole point of ajax calls is to stay on the same page - they do not redirect. If you want to redirect, then do a normal submit (there is no point using ajax)

Comment: I only know one way to get from the client to the server and it's by an AJAX call.

Comment: I mean have used form submits (if that count for a normal submit) but I thought they used AJAX too, under the hood.

Comment: Just put a `<input type="submit">` inside your form and construct you html correctly using strongly typed html helpers bound to your model properties and post back the model (use `LoginViewModel model`, not individual parameters) - no javascript/jquery required!

Comment: I think I get it. It make sense. I have done that a couple of times before. I never though deeper about the different I guess or maybe I just have a bad day. Thanks alot, for helping me again.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I worked like you said, thanks alot. Feel free to make an answer I can accept, you helped me more than you think.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments; this is not really best practice. However, to answer your question, the redirect does not happen as the browser is not handling the response directly. Your handling the response in your success method.

If you want to redirect as a result of an AJAX call which is dictated by the server you can use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        $("body").html(data);    //Providing the result is a response to redirect ONLY
    }
})
```

Effectively you are just overwriting the entire body with the response, which then the browser picks up as a redirect before anything is actually rendered.

However, if you take this approach you may want to cater for other status codes, the obvious being 500 because if you do this and there is an internal error; nothing will happen except a log to the browser console

Comment: This is how I usually does. Returning html from an AJAX call to set some div. This is not what I am looking for this time. This time I want to call my server action, do some login validation and if that goes well redirect to another action where the User can continue.